# REGEX - Combining positive lookaheads with conditionals?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Got another one for you here! I've been fiddling for a while but I'm getting lost. I think the maybe the key to acheiving this is in combining conditionals with positive lookaheads?

I want to always find the start of a string. I've called it `"MatchMe!"` in the example but in reality it can be anything. `Part 1`, `Part 2`, `Part 3` and `Part 4` are always the same (well not the same but I can regex these reliably)

Is there a way to try and do a positive lookahead with `Part 1`, if that doesn't exist, try a positive lookahead with `Part 2`, and if that doesn't exist try a positive lookahead with `Part 3`, and lastly try the same with `Part 4`? Or am I overcomplicating things

My lousy attempt is here but it gives an idea of my problem :-)

https://regex101.com/r/TvgXXB/1

Many thanks again!

Comment: Maybe [`^.*?(?=\s*(?:Part1|Part2|Part3|Part4))`](https://regex101.com/r/TvgXXB/3)?

Comment: "MatchOnlyMe!" if you check the link :)

Comment: Yeah, apologies. It's been a long day. Wiktor's regex should work for you then.

Comment: You closed capturing group too early. Move it to the end and use a *beginning of string / line* anchor.

Comment: Thanks guys! That was much simpler than I thought! :D I really need to read up on my anchors!

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
^.*?(?=\s*(?:Part1|Part2|Part3|Part4))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TvgXXB/3)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?=\s*(?:Part1|Part2|Part3|Part4))` - a location in string that, immediately to the right of it, is followed with

  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `(?:Part1|Part2|Part3|Part4)` - either of the alternatives listed in the [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do).